# Refactor this jQuery (it seems bloated)

Tags: jquery

I'm performing this very simple task using jQuery, this code works, but feels bloated and i'm sure theres a quicker way to do it:

menu and close are hidden by default.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var menu = $('#menu');
var open = $('.btnOpen');
var close = $('.btnClose');

open.click(function(){
    menu.show();
    open.hide();
    close.show();
});

close.click(function(){
    menu.hide();
    close.hide();
    open.show();
});
```

});

Comment: Seems alright to me. Though I'd group those 3 variables with one `var`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnOpen, .btnClose').click(function(){
        $('#menu, .btnOpen, .btnClose').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Less bloated, but slower than the original code. I would declare `$('#menu, .btnOpen, .btnClose')` as a variable so that you don't need to look it up on every `click()`.

Comment: Slower? Doubt it... The original called 3 functions - this calls the one, also the original explicitly declared two eventhandlers. jQuery is optimised for multiple element handling at once.. Granted perhaps declaring it as a function would save you 1 or 2 ms, but less bloated code is wanted.

Comment: @Michael: It's slower because it has to search the DOM again, which takes much more time than calling a function.

Comment: I'm not disputing that it will be slightly slower. In my comment, I meant declaring it as a variable.
Would only save a few ms, not a noticeable time.

Comment: @Michael Wright, I take your point that a difference of a few milliseconds is not worth worrying about. Interestingly, though, I just ran some speed tests and the original code completes in about 35% of the time it takes to run any answer on this page -- with or without declaring the variable separately. It seems combining selectors into a single string is a kiss of death in speed tests (ah, sorry, using `add()` is nearly as fast as the original code). Keep the selectors simple and they'll execute quickest.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.btnOpen, .btnClose').click(function(){
    $('.btnOpen, .btnClose, #menu').toggle();
});
```

Be sure to set their initial state properly through CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can group elements:

```
open.click(function(){
    menu.add(close).show();
    open.hide();
});

close.click(function(){
    menu.add(this).hide();
    open.show();
});
```

Or also possible (and shorter, but still reliable):

```
open.add(close).click(function(){
    var show = $(this).hasClass('btnOpen');
    menu.add(close).toggle(show);
    open.toggle(!show);
});
```

You could even store the a reference to `menu.add(close)` beforehand.

I would avoid just using `toggle`, to not get out of sync. Only if you are very sure that the visibility cannot change through anything else than through these buttons. And if fast/repeated clicking does not screw this up.

Answer (score 2):

Let's throw some more ideas in here... :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $buttons = $('.btnOpen,.btnClose');

    $buttons.click(function(){
        $buttons.add('#menu').toggle();
    });
});
```